# How to write dash 6 in author field using Bibtex

Tags: bibtex, author

My question is simple, I want to write the name of this author : **Wen-mei**

Here is my code :

```
 @inproceedings{intro_1, 
                title={Heterogeneous System Architecture: A New Compute Platform Infrastructure},
                author={Wen-mei W. Hwu},
                year={2015}}
```

But, the dash is not shown in the output :

[image]

Note that am obliged to use plain style, `\bibliographystyle{plain}` and
I tried to use some tricks like : `\` and `$ $` but it didn't work for me.

Comment: It's possible that this isn't an ascii hyphen, especially if you copied-and-pasted.  Check your log to see if there are any warnings about characters missing from a font.  Anyhow, go into your `.bib` file, erase the hyphen and retype it, then rerun bibtex and recompile the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did found a trick that allow me to write a dash 6 while using `\bibliographystyle{plain}`

I just wrote my `-` inside a parentheses ( like this `{-}`) so it worked as I wanted.